# Using stream to modify existing Excel file using ExcelJS

Tags: node.js, exceljs, nodejs-stream

I have a template Excel file and I need to write data to the file using a readable stream and then stream back the result file to server response for download.

This is what I've got so far, using [exceljs](https://github.com/guyonroche/exceljs). But it's not 'real' streaming cause the workbook was saved into memory before being sent to response.

```
const path = require('path')
const Excel = require('exceljs')
const dao = require('./dao')

const stream = dao.getData().stream()
const workbook = new Excel.Workbook()

workbook.xlsx.readFile(path.join(__dirname, 'Template.xlsx'))
.then(() => {
  const detailSheet = workbook.getWorksheet('Detail')
  detailSheet.columns = colName.header.detail

  stream.on('data', (d) => {
    detailSheet.addRow(d).commit()
  })

  stream.on('end', () => {
    workbook.xlsx.write(res)
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are using exceljs ([ExcelJS Package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/exceljs)). If not, this won't apply.

You initialize your workbooks differently if you want to use streaming. Rather than setting the workbook with a constructor you would do something along the lines of:

```
const workbook = new Excel.stream.xlsx.WorkbookReader(options);
```

Where options is:

```
{
    filename: 'filename'
}
```

The interface for writing is `Excel.stream.xlsx.WorkbookWriter(options);`

After that everything else can be done the same. The package does list some minor differences:

- Once a worksheet is added to a workbook, it cannot be removed.
- Once a row is committed, it is no longer accessible since it will have been dropped from the worksheet.
- unMergeCells() is not supported.

As long as you can work within those constraints the streaming option will likely be the most memory performant option for you.

Comment: Thanks, @dkimot. The WorkbookReader function is not mentioned on ExcelJs documentation, this is all I could find: https://github.com/guyonroche/exceljs/issues/63, but it seems like I have to get all data from the Template workbook and insert it again into the new workbook?
The point to use a template here is that there's some vba code I want to serve on the result workbook so I wonder how can I keep those vba code?

Comment: I dug through the code. I found first the code referencing it at https://github.com/guyonroche/exceljs/blob/master/lib/exceljs.nodejs.js. I'm not very familiar with this package. As I understand it, everything that was in the workbook file will remain in the workbook.

Comment: Sorry, I still can't get it. When I use Excel.stream.xlsx.WorkbookReader to stream the Template workbook, I cannot modify directly on it (cause workbook.getWorkSheet(...) is not existed)

Comment: Okay, because documentation is flawed I'm digging through code. This led to the workbook-reader object at https://github.com/guyonroche/exceljs/blob/master/lib/stream/xlsx/workbook-reader.js. Inside of that there appears to be an event that will be emitted called 'worksheet'. Can you check for that?